# FBA - Search Issue with Custom Login Page

Tags: 2010, search, forms-authentication, crawling, custom-login-page

I have implemented FBA on an web application which has a *custom login page*. The custom page doesn't let the users login via windows authentication even though it is enabled from central admin. Seems like when I have the custom login page enabled, search crawl fails for the web app. The search log shows the error below:

```
The SharePoint server was moved to a different location. ( Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode Found The request failed with the error message: -- <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a href="%2f_LAYOUTS%2fSharePoint.POC%2fLogin.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252f_vti_bin%252fsitedata.asmx">here</a>.</h2> </body></html> --. )
```

Taking off the custom login page and using the OOB FBA login page fixes the search issue. I understand I can extend the web app to use classic auth and have search crawl. Is there any other way around?

Comment: Custom login page only works with FBA users. I have tried this for windows authentication but i was unsuccessful for windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding a hidden URL in my custom login page as such:

```
<div style="display:none">
                <a href="/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/">click
                here to login</a>                    
            </div>
```

This URL lets users login with windows auth which I am hiding because I want users to login using forms. I am guessing search crawler looks out for this URL during a crawl.

Comment: This did not work for me actually. I didn't find out until I ran a full crawl. The following steps fixed the issue: extend the site which uses classic authentication (http://xyz) => add the newly created site to the content source => remove the main site (http://abc.com) => add new server mapping for http://xyz to http://abc.com. Not sure if there is an easier way to fix this issue.

Comment: Accept your own answer if you have resolved the issue, so question will not reflect in unanswered questions..